# Transformation of missing values by taking log(x+1)

Tags: r, variables, transformation

I am trying to learn R and I have a data frame which contains 68 continuous and categorical variables. There are two variables  -> x and lnx, on which I need help. Corresponding to a large number of 0's & NA's in x, lnx shows NA. Now, I want to write a code through which I can take log(x+1) in order to replace those NA's in lnx to 0, where corresponding x is also 0 (if x == 0, then I want only lnx == 0, if x == NA, I want lnx == NA). Data frame looks something like this -

```
  a       b       c       d       e      f         x        lnx
AB1001   1.00    3.00    67.00   13.90   2.63    1776.7     7.48
AB1002   0.00    2.00    72.00   38.70   3.66    0.00       NA
AB1003   1.00    3.00    48.00   4.15    1.42    1917       7.56
AB1004   0.00    1.00    70.00   34.80   3.55    NA         NA
AB1005   1.00    1.00    34.00   3.45    1.24    3165.45    8.06
AB1006   1.00    1.00    14.00   7.30    1.99    NA         NA
AB1007   0.00    3.00    53.00   11.20   2.42    0.00       NA
```

I tried writing the following code -

```
data.frame$lnx[is.na(data.frame$lnx)] <-  log(data.frame$x +1)
```

but I get the following warning message and the output is wrong:

number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. Can someone guide me please.

Thanks.

Comment: Just replace with 0 directly

Answer (score 1):

In R you can select rows using conditionals and assign values directly. In you example you could do this:

```
df[is.na(df$lnx) & df$x == 0,'lnx'] <- 0
```

Here's what this does:

`is.na(df$lnx)` returns a logical vector the length of `df$lnx` telling, for each row, whether lnx is `NA`. `df$x == 0` does the same thing, checking whether, for each row, `x == 0`. By using the `&` operator, we combine those vectors into one that contains `TRUE` only for rows where both conditions are `TRUE`.

We then use the bracket notation to select the `lnx` column of those rows where both conditions are `TRUE` in `df` and then insert the value 0 into those cells using `<-`

The specific error your getting is because `log(data.frame$x +1)` and `df$lnx[is.na(df$lnx)]` are different lengths. `log(data.frame$x +1)` produces a vector whose length is the number of rows of your data frame while the length of `df$lnx[is.na(df$lnx)]` is the number of rows that have `NA` in `lnx`

Answer (score 1):

Using a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(lnx = case_when(
    x == 0.0 ~ 0,
    is.na(x) ~ NA_real_))
```

This yields for your example:

```
# A tibble: 7 x 8
  a          b     c     d     e     f     x   lnx
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AB1001    1.    3.   67. 13.9   2.63 1777.   NA 
2 AB1002    0.    2.   72. 38.7   3.66    0.    0.
3 AB1003    1.    3.   48.  4.15  1.42 1917.   NA 
4 AB1004    0.    1.   70. 34.8   3.55   NA    NA 
5 AB1005    1.    1.   34.  3.45  1.24 3165.   NA 
6 AB1006    1.    1.   14.  7.30  1.99   NA    NA 
7 AB1007    0.    3.   53. 11.2   2.42    0.    0.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This makes sense but I cannot figure out how do I pass it through my data frame which has 68 columns. kindly help.

Comment: @Shank: Now, it's getting weird, please edit your question and provide real data. Without the data it's hard to help.

Comment: My bad. Apologies, I've edited the question. Hope this is helpful now.

Comment: @Shank: Updated, using `case_when()` now.